# Jägersprache: Unterschied zwischen »ausnehmen« und »ausweiden«

Tags: meaning, difference, technical-terminology

Die Wörter *ausnehmen* und *ausweiden* bedeuten (unter Anderem) den Vorgang, die Eingeweide aus einem Tier zu entfernen.

Im Duden ähneln sich die Definitionen stark.
Bei Grimm wird *[ausnehmen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GA08573#XGA08573)* auf Vieh, Vögel und Fische bezogen, *[ausweiden](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GA09332#XGA09332)* auf Wild:
Das kann aber daran liegen, dass die Listen nicht erschöpfend sind.

Wird in der Jägersprache ein Unterschied zwischen den beiden Wörtern gemacht, bzw. werden überhaupt beide verwendet?

Comment: Ich bin weder Jäger noch sonst vom Fach, daher nur als Kommentar: Ich verstehe unter _ausnehmen_ das geordnete entfernen der Eingeweide zB durch einen Fleischer. Bei _ausweiden_ denke ich eher an Raubtiere, die sich an einem Kadaver zu schaffen machen.

Comment: *Ausnehmen* ist Küchenlatein, *ausweiden* Jägerlatein

Comment: @raznagul Interessant, diesen Gebrauch von *ausweiden* (i. e.: speziell durch Tiere) hatte ich überhaupt nicht im Blick!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR:** In der Jägersprache werden beide Begriffe benutzt und sie haben unterschiedliche Bedeutung.

---

In [diesem Jagdlexikon](https://www.jagdschulatlas.de/jagdlexikon/) gibt es beide Einträge, sie beziehen sich aber auf unterschiedliche Tierarten.

> **[ausweiden](https://www.jagdschulatlas.de/jagdlexikon/ausweiden-1-141.html#141)** Das Herausnehmen des Gescheides bei allem Wild, außer beim Schalenwild.
>
> **[ausnehmen](https://www.jagdschulatlas.de/jagdlexikon/ausnehmen-1-130.html#130)** Das Ausweiden von kleinem Federwild.

Die Einträge in [diesem Jagdlexion](http://deutsches-jagd-lexikon.de) sind ähnlich:

> **[Ausweiden](http://deutsches-jagd-lexikon.de/index.php?title=Ausweiden)**  Ausweiden, selten benutzer[sic] Ausdruck für das Entfernen des Gescheides bei Wild, außer Schalenwild (Aufbrechen).
>
> **[Ausnehmen](http://deutsches-jagd-lexikon.de/index.php?title=Ausnehmen)**
>   1. Ausweiden von kleinem Federwild.
>   2. Entnahme von Eiern oder Küken aus einem Gelege oder Horst.
>   3. veraltete Bezeichnung für Aufbrechen

Wie der Eintrag oben schon andeutet, heißt der selbe Vorgang beim Schalenwild *aufbrechen*. Zur Ergänzung noch der Eintrag:

> **[Aufbrechen](http://deutsches-jagd-lexikon.de/index.php?title=Aufbrechen)**, Herausnehmen des Gescheides und Geräuschs (Aufbruchs) bei Schalenwild. Früher war der Ausdruck nur bei Hochwild gebräuchlich.

Das Ausweiden von Hase und Kaninchen heißt **[Auswerfen](http://deutsches-jagd-lexikon.de/index.php?title=Auswerfen)**.

Es gibt auch noch weitere Fachbegriffe, die sich dann auf eine bestimmte Technik beim Ausnehmen oder auf bestimmte Körperteile beziehen können, wie z.B.: Ausdrücken, Ausfahren, Aushaken.

---

Nur zur Ergänzung:

> Als [Schalenwild](http://deutsches-jagd-lexikon.de/index.php?title=Schalenwild) bezeichnet man alle dem Jagdrecht unterliegenden Paarhufer, da ihre Hufe als Schalen bezeichnet werden.
>   In Deutschland sind das nach § 2. Abs. 1 BJagdG. zehn Wildarten:
>   Rotwild
>   Damwild
>   Sikawild
>   Muffelwild
>   Schwarzwild
>   Steinwild
>   Gamswild
>   Rehwild
>   Elch
>   Wisent
>   Alles Schalenwild, außer Rehwild gehört zum [Hochwild](http://deutsches-jagd-lexikon.de/index.php?title=Hochwild).
>
> Zum [Hochwild](http://deutsches-jagd-lexikon.de/index.php?title=Hochwild) zählt nach § 2, Abs. 1 BJagdG. alles Schalenwild, außer Rehwild, sowie Auerwild, Stein- und Seeadler.

Comment: Hinweis: Man kann auch Fische ausnehmen.

Comment: @Iris Stimmt, das ist aber m.E. eher was für die Angler, als die Jäger (wobei es da Überschneidungen geben mag).